# Need some help to understand differentiability of function of several variables.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Note: if someone knows a better title, please let me know so I adjust it.

I am reading calculus of several variables by Serge Lang, 3rd ed. (pages 77-79) and need some help with derivative of a function of several variables.
The author after talking about vectors, dot product, defined the gradient algebraically only. Now he tries to differentiate a function of several variables as follows:
$ \frac{f(X+H)- f(X)}{H}$ where both $H$ and $X$ are vectors, with $\|H\|$ being small. He says it is meaningless to **divide by a vector**, so he does the following(all in single variable and not in vector):

Let $ \phi(x) = \frac{f(x+h)- f(x)}{h} - f'(x)$ as the limit of h approaches zero, $\phi(x)$ also approaches zero.
then:

$h\phi(x) + hf'(x) = f(x+h) - f(x)$

then he defines $ g(x) = -\phi(x)$ if $h < 0 $

and $g(x) = \phi(x)$ if $h > 0 $

I don't understand what is the point of defining $g(x)$ here?

nevertheless, the equation now becomes:

$ f(x+h) - f(x) = hf'(x) + \|h\|g(x) $ saying that this form has an advantage of no division by $h$ thus, he will use this form to define differentiability for function of several variables.

but without pretty much adding anything to that he does the following:

$f(X + H) - f(X) = f(x + h, y + k) - f(x,y)\\
f(x+h, y+k) - f(x, y)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}h + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}k + \|H\|g(H)$

I don't understand where this expression is coming from. for one, multiplying a vector is not defined or talked about, there are at least 4 ways that I know of to multiply 2 vectors (dot, cross, outer and Hammard) I don't know why he changed the expression $ h f'(x) $ to be $\nabla f \cdot H$ multiplication is not the dot product (why would it be changed to be that?), another issue is that the derivative should account for change in all components and not just one component at a time. honestly, that expression gave me so many questions, I would appreciate if someone can explain it.

I attach below photos for the 3 pages, just in case someone wants to read the original pages, in case they think I made a mistake or missed something of importance. [image: 77]
[image: 78] [image: 79]

Comment: The idea of a derivative can be characterized as a linear approximation of a function i.e. approximation in the neighborhood of a point by a linear function. The same is true in the case of vector variables: the function is approximated in the neighborhood of a point by a linear hypersurface. Therefore, the product is scalar.

Comment: Is there a place where can I read about this justification in more detail?

Comment: Hastily, books: Vladimir A. Zorich (auth.) - Mathematical Analysis II-Springer (2016), page 61, James J. Callahan (auth.) - Advanced calculus_ A geometric view-Springer-Verlag New York (2010), from page 71. Online: MIT text https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter06/section01.html

Comment: You might try the appropriate lectures in my YouTube lectures on multivariable calculus and linear algebra. They’re linked in my profile. (There’s also a text, but I’m not trying to drum up business.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much ted, I watched some of the first videos. And the rest are on my watch list. It's just I feel the definition is out of context in the way it was presented in the book I am reading. So I was hoping someone can clarify it.